# Registration Process Bar CSS3 animation

Tags: html, angularjs, css

[image: Example]

What is a good way to implement this feature?

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should I add those numbers on the progress-bar as photos?
or I should draw the circle by CSS3? If so, could anyone provide an example?

Comment: Use CSS and text... Images can't be read by machines

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick live demo of how one could start creating this type of visual in CSS. This example is quick and dirty, so to adapt it for production I would recommend simplifying some of the CSS and possibly generating the HTML using JavaScript and maybe some CSS pseudoelements. Then I would look into animating the colors using CSS animations. This is just to give you an idea of how it could be done, and maybe spark some ideas.

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of demo]

**Live Demo:**

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #555048;
}

.segment {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A8A9AD;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.line {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #A8A9AD;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
.label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #A8A9AD;
}
.container {
    margin: 50px;
}
.segment.active .circle, .segment.active .line {
    background-color: #C0A05F;
}
.segment.active .label {
    color: #C0A05F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="segment active"><div class="circle">1</div><div class="label">PERSONAL</div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="segment active"><div class="circle">2</div><div class="label">PROFILE</div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="segment"><div class="circle">3</div><div class="label">EXPERIENCE</div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="segment"><div class="circle">4</div><div class="label">SETTING</div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="segment"><div class="circle">5</div><div class="label">CERTIFICATE</div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="segment"><div class="circle">6</div><div class="label">SUBMIT</div></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/8hxqunLx/1/

Answer (score 1):

## Let's create something clean and beautiful!

The end result:

[image: Finished]

### The HTML

This is a good place for an ordered list. All we need is this:

```
<ol>
    <li class="complete">Personal</li>
    <li class="complete">Profile</li>
    <li>Experience</li>
    <li>Setting</li>
    <li>Certificate</li>
    <li>Submit</li>
</ol>
```

When a step is complete, give it the `complete` class to change the steps background colour.

### The CSS

#### The numbers

> There is an in-depth write up of `counter` over on [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/css-generated-content-counters/#inserting-counters).

The numbers are created with a counter which looks like this stripped to the basics:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: counter;
}        

ol li::before {
  content: counter(counter, decimal);
}
```

The `counter-increment` property provides the correct number which is placed inside with `content` in a [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

The numbers are then positioned above the text with `position: absolute`.

#### The progress bar

> Read more about pseudo-elements [over here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

It looks like this and goes behind the numbers:

[image: Progress bar]

It is created with a `::before` pseudo element with a background gradient. Change the two middle percentage values (at 40% in this example) as the form is completed:

```
ol::before {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, #BFA15F 0, #BFA15F 40%, #A8A9AD 40%, #A8A9AD 100%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 6px;
}
```

#### Style the numbers

The numbers are inserted with `ol li::before`, which can be styled further:

- `border-radius: 50%` to create a circle
- `text-align: center` and `line-height: 20px` to perfectly center in the circle
- a background colour which is changed as the steps are completed.

### Complete Example

**Note**: There is no whitespace between the closing `</li>` tag and the next opening `<li>`. This prevents a gap between the `inline-block` list items. [Read more here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*white-space: nowrap; means -- don't wrap the text*/
}
ol::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #BFA15F 0, #BFA15F 40%, #A8A9AD 40%, #A8A9AD 100%);
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 6px;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: counter;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(counter, decimal);
  position: absolute;
  background: #A8A9AD;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*Matches height value*/
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ol li.complete::before {
  background: #BFA15F;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="complete">Personal</li><li class="complete">Profile</li><li>Experience</li><li>Setting</li><li>Certificate</li><li>Submit</li>
</ol>
```

#### Animated example

If the progress bar should animate, you could create it with two pseudo elements, instead of the gradient, with the gold line sliding over the gray.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*white-space: nowrap; means -- don't wrap the text*/

}

ol::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  background: #A8A9AD;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 6px;
}
ol::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  background: #BFA15F;
  left: 50px;
  top: 6px;

  animation: stretch 2s linear infinite;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: counter;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(counter, decimal);
  position: absolute;
  background: #A8A9AD;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*Matches height value*/
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
}
ol li.complete::before {
  background: #BFA15F;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
 width: 0;
  }
  100% {
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="complete">Personal</li><li class="complete">Profile</li><li>Experience</li><li>Setting</li><li>Certificate</li><li>Submit</li>
</ol>
```